# Getting Wrong Date While Using  Date Picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I took a baseViewController With a UIDatePicker.I am using this date picker in other viewControllers. When i am trying to get a date.always the previous date is showing up in the log.this is happening in every view controller.

getting a datepicker.

```
    self.datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.datePicker resignFirstResponder];
```

Taking the Value from a textfield using a date picker.

```
- (IBAction)dateValueChanged:(id)sender
{
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
dateSelected = [picker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
if (self.field.tag == 101)
    self.field.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateSelected];
NSLog(@"%@",dateSelected);
}
```

Comment: Please add a breakpoint to your second method, and check the value of `dateSelected`. Are you using ARC? Are both these methods within the asme class?

Comment: even in the log i am getting the previous date...and yes both these methods are in the same class

Comment: looks like its a problem with the date picker.the date value changed method is returning the previous date.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're editing the value of your entity but you are not persisting it. Try adding something like the following at the end of your `save` method:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Comment: @Sekhar It's not really about luck... Do you get a value returned in the `error` variable?

Comment: There's not much more to work on here. You're going to have to better explain what you've tried.

Comment: i am able to save the date but previous date is getting saved....i added the lines as u said.posted the updated code.

Comment: Is `dateValueChanged:` getting called? Is `save:` getting called?

Comment: yes sir.,without those two getting called i cant save the data.but i can save it and also i can retrieve them in other view.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, try getting rid of the autorelease, and see if your behavior changes.